# how to fix django instance of a model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Error message** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'

am trying to create an instance of a model.
the card model is suppose to be an instance of the patient model and the patient model has a foreign key relations with the user model.
Its like a patient who has a card in the hospital.

My error is coming from the perform_create method

**views.py**

```
class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,  ) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
        serializer.instance.owner.add(self.request.user)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from authentication.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        


class Card(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)    
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Patient, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be as

```
class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner = self.request.user)
```

Comment: I have treid it now and am having same error..............   **line 48, in perform_create
    model_instance.owner.add(self.request.user)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'**

Comment: @JosephAyemlo Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    model_instance = serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

OR

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    model_instance = serializer.save()
    model_instance.owner = self.request.user
```

**Edited**
..............
A closer look at your model shows that you need to redefine the model.  As you've defined, the *owner* field under Patient class indicated that you can have a User who can be many Patient...(a query of: `patient=Patient.objects.get(owner=self.request.user)` may return more than one instance. ).  Suggested model should be:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    **owner = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)**
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Card(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)    
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Patient, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then you can have your view:

```
class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,  ) 
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        card_instance = serializer.save()
        patient = Patient.objects.get(owner=self.request.user)
        card_instance.owner = patient
```

Comment: TypeError: save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: user00@example.com>": "Card.owner" must be a "Patient" instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Appreciation**
I was almost discouraged with programming for the past 24hrs because of this problem, but this community helped me, even though they did not give the answer i needed, they led me into discovering the answer myself, and i say Thank you to stackoverflow community...

**Solved**
I finally discovered what i was doing wrong.
a card does not just belong to a patient, it also belongs to a hospital, so the card needs a relation to both the hospital and the patient.

**models.py**

```
 class Patient(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name      
    
    class Card(models.Model):    
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        card_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)    
        owner = models.OneToOneField(Patient, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        hospital = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,  )         
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(hospital=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(hospital=self.request.user)

class PatientCardDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(hospital=self.request.user)
```